# How to use an launch file in xml document to get the parameters to be used in a cpp file

Tags: ros

There are parameters needed to be set in a .cpp file in ROS. These parameters are to be obtained from the launch file.How to set those parameters from launch file in a .cpp file using ros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I reccommend you to follow [this simple tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams) and read the [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam) and [roscpp Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) documentation. Everything should become very easy.

---

A simple **launch file** example is as following:

```
<launch>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find pkg_name)/path/file_name.yaml" />
  <node pkg="pkg_name" type="node_type" name="node_name" />
</launch>
```

Where you should set your own package name and the other variables. You could find the meanings of all these parameters in the following links: [param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) and [node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).

---

Than you have to retrieve those parameters from your **C++ source code** (have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists)):

```
/* this handle let you access all the parameters of the node (and other stuffs) */
ros::NodeHandle node_handle = new ros::NodeHandle("~");

/* for example if I need to retrieve a list of double written in the YAML file,
   I could call the getParam() method to store it into my_double_list std::vector */
std::vector<double> my_double_list;
node_handle.getParam("name_of_the_list_in_YAML_file", my_double_list);

/* print data retrieved */
std::copy(my_double_list.begin(), my_double_list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
```

Where the **YAML file** should be something like this (4 elements in the example):

```
name_of_the_list_in_YAML_file: [123.11, 0.1, 2013.441, 1.23015e+3]
```

For more details: [YAML](http://wiki.ros.org/YAML%20Overview). You can also find the `ros::NodeHandle` documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html).